# how to read manifest.mf in an j2me application

Tags: java-me, manifest, lwuit, manifest.mf, meta-inf

I'm developing a j2me application using Netbeans IDE and LWUIT library. I need to read some attributes of MANIFEST.MF that are included in jar file.
What all I found in net, either have conflict with j2me or are not working with Netbeans.
How to read these attributes at run time?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Display.getInstance().getProperty()` to extract custom values from the jad.

Comment: thanks Shai Almog
but i want to extract values from MANIFEST.MF not jad.
ias this method working for both??

Comment: To some degree. Only elements mirrored in the manifest will appear.